# Update tables based on info in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with information about another tables. Like this:

`AccTableHistory`:

```
| TableName| ColumnName  |
| -------- | ----------- |
| Table1   | FirstName   |
| Table1   | LastName    |
| Table1   | Adress      |
| Table2   | FirstName   |
| Table2   | SSN         |
| Table2   | FamilyStatus|
```

etc.

I need to write an update statement for each column from this list.
Should be something like:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET 
   FirstName = 'Andrew'
  ,LastName  = 'Test'
  ,Adress    = 'Test'
```

But we have more than 100 tables and more than 800 columns in the list. I don't want to write an update for each table manually.

Is it possible to write a dynamic query or stored procedure to update each table from this list (AccTableHistory table)?

I have no idea how to achieve that

Comment: You could build some dynamic SQL which uses the meta data to build the update.

Comment: @DaleK you mean systables?

Comment: Indeed.........

Comment: You will need to use [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for your dynamic SQL

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have? And where would you get the values from?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = (
SELECT '
    UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' ' + 'SET' + ' ' + c.name + ' ' + '=' + ' ' + 'TestValue'
FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name IN (SELECT TableName FROM AccHistory) AND c.name IN (SELECT ColumnName FROM AccHistory)

    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: the condition `c.name IN (SELECT ColumnName FROM AccHistory)` is flawed. You should just use INNER JOIN. Like `INNER JOIN AccHistory a ON t.name = a.TableName and c.name = a.ColumnName`

Comment: Also where is `TestValue` coming from, is it a column in each table?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).